# Android ListView jumps back to top after setting inital scroll position and tapping it

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

Hey there fellow Android developers!
If I initially set the scroll-position of a ListView it will be displayed scrolled to the position I want it to. But when I touch the ListView it will immediately jump back to the top. Do you have any ideas how to fix that easily? 
Some simple code to replicate that issue (with data being a random String array):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
    mListView.scrollTo(0,100);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use mListView.setSelection() ? pass an int to that function and tell it upto which item it has scroll to. I think that works fine enough.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't work for me, I need to set it to an absolute scroll position, not to a specific item.